# List all fields of query with subquery

Tags: soql, sobject

I have this query: `List<sobject> query_result = Database.query(query);`

with query = SELECT Email,Fax,(SELECT Status,Type FROM Cases),(SELECT CreatedDate FROM Tasks)FROM Contact WHERE Id =

How can I browse all results (Cases, Tasks , Contact) to store them separately in new lists?

Answer (score 6):

To access the related lists you first need to cast the generic SObject type to the correct type:

```
List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();
for (SObject sob : query_result) {
    Contact c = (Contact) sob;
    contactList.add(c);
    List<Case> caseList = c.Cases;
    List<Task> taskList = c.Tasks;
    // Do whatever you want here with the lists
}
```

Bear in mind that you will have a separate list of cases and tasks per contact.

You don't explain why you are using a dynamic query; it would be simpler to just use static SOQL:

```
List<Contact> contactList = [select ... from Contact ... where ...];
for (Contact c : contactList) {
    List<Case> caseList = c.Cases;
    List<Task> taskList = c.Tasks;
    // Do whatever you want here with the lists
}
```

**PS**

If you want to avoid any specific types and just use [SObject](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) methods:

```
for (SObject sob : query_result) {
    List<SObject> caseList = sob.getSObjects('Cases');
    List<SObject> taskList = sob.getSObjects('Tasks');
    // Do whatever you want here with the lists
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using dynamic query because I'm building app where user choose fields for a SObject & children, I store choices and I have to query and display results in vfp

Comment: @AmineDarkaoui Makes sense. Just wanted to ask because sometimes dynamic SOQL is used where static SOQL would be better.

Comment: Is it possible to replace c.Cases with c.get('Cases') so I can dynamically get all the child fields without using static declaration.

Comment: @AmineDarkaoui Yes there is an [SObject.getSObjects](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_getSObjects) method that does that. There are several other methods that you may find useful too so take a look at the [sObject Class](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) documentation. So if you want to you can implement the whole thing without explicit types. See the added "PS".